# MVC application Authorization for ApiController doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, postman, asp.net-authorization

I'm building an MVC application that has standard Controllers and APIControllers in the same  project. All functionality works fine, I can call Controllers or APIControllers no issues.

What I'm trying to achieve is to make sure that if you call /api/products from outside it shouldn't be accessible, only authorized users can call it.

I added and Authorize attribute to my api controller and I still can call it and get results from a client application like Postman. You can see my code below.

```
 [Authorize] //System.Web.Http
 public class ProductsController : ApiController 

 [HttpGet]
 public IHttpActionResult Get()
```

Here is what I have in my Startup.Auth.cs file.

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
```

If I commented out this code, I get a proper response from the APIController, but I also cannot login.

```
<Error>
<Message>Authorization has been denied for this request.</Message>
</Error>
```

Not sure what I'm missing. Per my understanding I don't need to create a custom Filter for my API controllers, I should be able to use a built in Authorization functionality. Let me know if you need more details or code samples.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the auth for your MVC controllers is defined by `Startup.Auth.cs` while for the API controllers is at `WebApiConfig.cs`.

Make sure that on `WebApiConfig.cs` in the `Register()` method you have a call to `config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();` which prevents the configured authentication method on your MVC controllers to work on `ApiController` calls.

Also note that you must need, in certain cases, to add the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute in some API calls like login, register, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting findings. I tried to call the API Controllers that are required authentication from within the application without authorization and I received a proper response, Not Authorized. I tried to call the API endpoint using Fiddler, the same result.

So for some reason, Postman still can get results without any errors. I created even a new API endpoint the same behavior. I'm going to refrain from using the Postman because even it's a great tool it creates a lot of confusion, and as a result, I wasted a few hours.

Hopefully, my example is going to save somebody else time.

Comment: Is it possible that you used PostMan BEFORE you added the [Authorize] attribute, and therefore it has cached a (temporarily) valid token?  If you try it today (assuming the token has expired), do you get the same results?